# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash

Can anyone point out the error in the following bash script

```
 for i in {0..127} ; do echo -n [$i] ; if [$i -eq 7]; then echo "\n" ; mytool-c "read 0x1540:0xa0:$i*$j" ; done
```

Comment: you forget to close the `if` block through `fi`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing spaces in the `if` line. It needs to be `[ $i -eq 7 ]`. (`[` is a command.)

But your error is that you are missing the closing `fi` for the `if`.